# disable warning "use var instead of explicit type" for certain types only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If I write code like this:

`int five = 2 + 3;`

VS warns me that I should "use var instead of explicit type". I'm actually ok with that warning in a lot of circumstances, but not here. The word "int" is just as short as "var" and a little more informative. So in this case, I think "int" is actually better.

Even in this case, I wish it wouldn't warn me:

`bool ok = Condition1() && Condition2();`

By contrast, I'm glad it warns me in a case like this:

`MyReallyLongTypeName<LongTypeParameter> foo = SomeFunction();`

So I guess I'm wondering if there is a way to disable that warning for a few types, but keep it for most types.

Comment: I don't think this is actually a warning and is more likely to be a hint. I think this down to your personal preferences though. It's unlikely you could turn this off without writing your own Roslyn analyzer

Comment: Assuming you're on a modern VS and its own analysers (rather than e.g. Resharper), `.editorconfig` breaks down the var preferences by "Built-in types", "when type is apparent" and "Elsewhere" - so if it's just for the built-in types it looks like you're in luck.

Comment: The "'var' preference" options are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/language-rules).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio search for "preferences"
[image]

Then search for "var"

[image]

There you can select if you prefer explicit types.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It might solve the problem for many people who come here via a search (hence the upvotes, I assume), but it is not helpful for the question asked. Finding the "'var' preferences" (even for built-in types specifically, which are not mentioned in this answer) is not a solution for disabling the inspection "for certain types only". In its current form, the question is not about built-in types nor about configuring the "'var' preferences" in general. Being explicit about whether this is even possible "for certain types only" would make it an answer.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer if you read the question, you can see that this is exactly what the question was about. 100% of what was wanted can be done using my answer. If you want to do something else you could ask a new question.

Comment: I came here looking to disable this warning for just a specific type, as the title suggested, so I'm in the same frustrating situation as @RaimundKrämer unfortunately.

I read the question and still think this answer does not answer the question. The question clearly says " I'm wondering if there is a way to disable that warning for a few types, but keep it for most types.", but the answer changes all preferences globally.